# MPMediaPickerController in UINavigationController

Tags: ios

I would like to use an MPMediaPickerController in a navigation controller.

This does work:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MusicImport" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *nav = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
self.picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
self.picker.showsCloudItems = NO;
self.picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
// add to dummy VC's view
[[nav.viewControllers[0] view] addSubview:self.picker.view]; 
nav.navigationBarHidden = YES;
nav.delegate = self;
self.mainNav = nav;
```

I then push my custom view controller when the user selects an item in the picker:

```
self.selectedItem = mediaItemCollection.items[0];
self.playbackViewController = [[PlaybackViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlaybackViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.playbackViewController.mediaItem = self.selectedItem;
self.playbackViewController.delegate = self;

self.mainNav.navigationBar.tintColor = self.picker.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor;
self.mainNav.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.mainNav pushViewController:self.playbackViewController animated:YES];
```

so far, so good. only problem here is that the tintColor thing does not work.
the real problem is that when navigating back from my custom playback VC, the media picker does not become visible.

Even when I'm trying to add it back in the navigation controller's delegate method:

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(viewController == navigationController.viewControllers[0])
    {
        [viewController.view addSubview:self.picker.view];
        navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    }
}
```

alas, no dice.

Comment: Why don't you simply push the media picker controller onto navigation stack: `[nav pushViewController:self.picker]` instead of adding a subview?

Comment: ah yes, this seems to work. i had tried this but apparently done it wrong earlier, hence the hack. thanks!

Comment: unfortunately, this produces a warning log: `WARNING: MPMediaPickerController must be presented modally.` I do not want this to be the reason for App Store rejection :)